# Elasticsearch match all keywords inside given larger text

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to build a terminology dictionary using elasticsearch.

In Elasticsearch all entries are like this:

```
{ item: 'mouse', definition: 'some text here'},
{ item: 'mouse click', definition: 'some text here'},
{ item: 'mouse pointer', definition: 'some text here'},
{ item: 'left mouse button', definition: 'some text here'},
{ item: 'primary button', definition: 'some text here' }
```

Given a text for search eg:

"A left-click involves clicking the mouse left button. Typically, "left-clicking" means the same thing as just "clicking" since the left mouse button is the primary button by default."

I'm trying to achieve matching of all "items" in elasticsearch as exact phrases and partial of text using the longest exact phrase. In the above example the matched terms should be:

"left mouse button" and "primary button" and not the "mouse" or "mouse click"

Is this possible using elastic search?

Comment: what kind of query did you try already?

Comment: I tried match, fuzzy, span with many variations, but as I understand all these searches are used to match the given term against all entries. I kind want the opposite. In given term, match all entries from larger to smallest length as phrase.

Comment: ah, i got it, you want to provide long text and match documents that contains at least some terms from that text, right?

Comment: Yes exactly. And also control the way matches are performed. Longer excact phrase matches should score more than single words. Is this possible with elaaticsearch?

Comment: It seems that using a plain "query_string" search, I get results as expected, but also its matching more terms than needed.